# 400 error displayed when sharing page to facebook

Tags: facebook, debugging, http-status-code-400

When sharing page to Facebook from website the facebook share window reports that the page url is returning a 400 error and is not shareable. In contrast the Facebook debugger tool reports that the page is OK after rescraping.

I am expecting that since the url is displayed when requested, that sharing to Facebook would not be an issue.

Wondering if anyone has experienced this issue before and if so what was done to resolve the issue

Further details:
When using the facebook debugger tool and rescraping the page url it is reported that the page is OK.  Regardless of the number of times that the page is scraped using the debugging tool subsequent shares to facebook from the site page fail with the same error.

Affected [web page](https://perfectpets.com.au/l/For+Sale/dogs/schnauzer-miniature/miniature-schnauzer-puppies-6/NSW/2444)

Comment: The AddThis script you used for sharing shares the URL with `/For%20Sale/` instead of `/For+Sale/`, and Facebook had a 400 response code cached for _that_ URL. After re-scraping that “other version”, share preview now looks fine. Your `og:url` meta element contains an unencoded space in that place, with mistakes like that you mustn’t be too surprised if things go wrong at some point.

Comment: Makes sense and simple fix.  Thanks @misorude